# time complexity of (A[i]^x)>(A[i]&x)

Tags: c++, optimization, xor

'Is it possible to further optimize the time complexity this piece of calculation "(y^x)>(y&x)" in c++?(you are allowed to change the Boolean operation into other forms, for example this can also be written as log2(y)!=log2(x) and this gives the same Boolean output but this has a higher time complexity with c++ compiler)'`enter code here`

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int t;cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n;cin>>n;int A[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){cin>>A[i];}
        int q;cin>>q;
       while(q--){
           int l,r,x;
           cin>>l>>r>>x;int count=0;
           for(int i=l-1;i<r;i++){
               if((A[i]^x)>(A[i]&x)){count++;}
           }
           cout<<count<<endl;
       } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

'This is the code im trying to optimize.... Please help in any way possible (number of inputs cant be changed)'

Comment: `(y^x)>(y&x)` in itself is efficient, it's not the problem, you need a different overall algorithm so that you don't need to count one-by-one. IDK what this code does though, so I can't suggest a different algorithm, please add more detail.

Comment: The time-complexity is more about the presence of three nested loops, not about the math inside the innermost loop.

Comment: A number M is said to be a Mystical Number with respect to a number X if (M^X)>(M&X), we are trying to find the number of mystical numbers in  an array A wrt x; There are T test cases each representing an array and q quires each quiery has the start and end index of the array, upto which we need to calculate the number of mystical numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(y^x)>(y&x)` is equivalent to `nlz(y) != nlz(x)` where `nlz` is a function that returns the number of leading zeroes of its input.

Therefore in order to count how often `(A[i]^x)>(A[i]&x)` is true for items in the array `A`, we could make a small array `N` where `N[j]` is the number of elements with `nlz(A[i]) == j` in array `A`. Then the number of times that `(A[i]^x)>(A[i]&x)` is true is equivalent to `n - N[nlz(x)]`.

That way there is no loop over `A` where it really matters. Creating the array `N` still requires a loop over `A`, but only once for each iteration of the outer loop, not for each individual `x`.

C++20 has the `nlz` function built in under the name [`std::countl_zero`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countl_zero).